# Return JSON from dotnet

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a minimal hosting model in ASP.NET Core. The main looks like this:

```
async static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // Display the number of command line arguments.
    Console.WriteLine(args.Length);

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    var app = builder.Build();


    app.MapGet("/P", (string symbol, int dte, string cop, double s, double k) => GetP(symbol, dte, cop, s, k));
    var base_url = "http://*:5151";
    app.Run(base_url);
}

async private static Task<double> 
GetP(string symbol, int dte, string cop, double spot, double strike)
    {
        double retVal = -1;

        return retVal

    }
```

Of course, right now it returns -1. But what if I would like to return a more `JSON` style result that looks something like this (array of records) in a browser:

```
[{"name":"AAPL","description":"P","days":123,"iv":0.2311,"rf":0.0364,"dy":0.0018,"spot":165.38,"strike":182.85,"metric":0.2331}]
```

What is the standard way to do this in `dotnet?` Is it something like this?

```
public JsonResult JsonResult()  
{  
      var name = "AAPL";  
      var description = "P";
      ...

      return Json(new { //what goes in here? });  
}
```

Comment: Look up _anonymous types_ in C#.  You want something like `new { name="AAPL", description = "P", days = 123, etc};`

Comment: Generally in .net, you would have a class that is modeled after your data and not instantiate your data this way (although you *can* use anonymous types). .. so name, description, etc would be exposed as properties  of a class and handled by the Json serialize stuff.  It makes this seamless.  See [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-JsonResult-example-Return-JSON-data-from-Controller-to-View-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) for an example.

Comment: @Flydog57, ok, but then what is the return value? Task<IActionResult>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the return type to a simple array:

```
private static Task<double[]> GetP(
  string symbol,
  int dte,
  string cop,
  double spot,
  double strike) =>
  Task.FromResult(new double[] { -1 });
```

The default serializer in minimal API should be able to interpret this as a JSON array. Also, if you change the type to a complex type, it should pick those up automatically.

Comment: Very nice - it works automatically converting the complex type to JSON